# Многозадачность Arduino для опроса модуля времени

Tags: время, arduino, таймер

Имеется шим:

```
TCCR1A = 0;
TCCR1B = 0;
ICR1 = PWM_PERIOD;
TCCR1A = (1 << WGM11);
TCCR1B = (1 << WGM13) | (1 << WGM12) | (1 << CS10);
tccrOff = TCCR1A;
TCCR1A |= (1 <<  COM1A1);
tccrOn = TCCR1A;
OCR1A = PWM_PULSE_DEFAULT;
```

Имеется функция управления портами output(); и модуль времени DS1307 (используется библиотека *DS1307RTC.h*).

Чип atmega328p, кварц на 8МГц.

Необходимо запускать функцию output() постоянно в цикле программы для вывода данных на дисплей.

Проблема в том, что когда output() находится в цикле программы, то при опросе модуля времени происходят мерцания и просадки по вольтажу на момент опроса.
Как функцию output() запускать в фоне от основного цикла программы и не управлять при этом другими пинами (так как сама функция управляет пинами через порты), к примеру через таймер?

Comment: Можно ли допустим запустить таймер OCR0A или OCR2A без управления пинами, с интервалом в 1мс?

Answer (score 0):

Просто нужно добавить ещё один микроконтроллер. Один будет заниматься сервисными функциями, другой отвечать за интерфейс пользовательский.

Comment: У меня на одном мк неопиксели на паттернах, шим контроллер и куча других задач, неужели нельзя обойтись одним? Всё работает, кроме этого нюанса.

Comment: То есть не критично.

Comment: Критично, потому что нет возможности ставить вторую атмегу. Я так уже делал, но это совсем другая история...

Comment: Некритично, потому что вы делаете устройство ради тех, кто не готов платить за 2 атмеги. Откуда у старушки, стремящейся идти в ногу с технологическим прогрессом, найдутся 250 рублей?

Comment: Глупости, я сказал нет возможности ставить вторую атмегу.

Comment: Значит, некритично.

Comment: Критично, что не критично - это ваше личное мнение а не участника вопроса, но так реализовывать  будете только Вы, жаль никто больше не участвует в дискуссии, не хватает полемики... С наступающим.

Comment: Никак не могу понять, почему в устройство, в которое требуется добавить второй микроконтроллер, чтобы обеспечить многозадачность, разработчик отказывается его добавить. Но при этом жалуется, что возможностей одного микроконтроллера ему не хватает для обеспечения комфортного использования. Что критично, а что не критично в данном случае - возникает резонный вопрос.

Comment: Согласен, вопрос резонный, но задача стоит реализовать на одном микроконтроллере.